# Distributing a java plugin's functionality elegantly - general Java / OOP noob issue

Tags: java, oop, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to split up functionality of a plugin I wrote for Bukkit and I'm not quite sure what the best way to do it would be.

Would it make sense to split it into

- AdCommons (with the main information, like a list of worlds, players, loaded subplugins, etc),
- AdTime (which handles time speed and some other stuff) and
- AdWeather (which handles the weather on the worlds)?

If so, how would I make all subplugins be able to "add" information to the main plugin (for example the duration of a day in that world)?

Is this even the right approach and if so, how do I make it work? I'm sorry if that has been asked, didn't quite know what to look for. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you want a Bukkit Plugin to change Weather, Time, list online players and so on.

But you shouldn't spilt that all up. It is easier for you if you do that in one Project.
If you want a organised plugin you only should use packages and classes. The bukkit wiki shows you how to do it.

[Bukkit Plugin Tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial)

I use it myself for my plugins.